# How to call multiple API synchronise in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-functions

Below is the code I have,

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

var config = {
    userName: 'XXXX',
    password: 'XXXX',
    server: 'XXXX',
    options: {
        database: 'XXXX',
        encrypt: true
    }
}

var connection = new Connection(config);

connection.on('connect', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        // // queryDatabase();
    }
}
);
```

There is huge chaining in my code because of asynchronize execution of code. I found [some libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync), but don't think to use them for production purpose.

How to call 'connect' synchronize and continue sequential flow of the code? What is the best way to achieve sequential execution of the code in Node.js ?

Comment: You can't continue normal flow.  Instead, you have to continue the flow inside the callback function or in a function you call from there.  That's how async programming works in nade.js.

Comment: node.js that is*

Answer (score 1):

would something like this work ?

```
var config = {
    userName: 'XXXX',
    password: 'XXXX',
    server: 'XXXX',
    options: {
        database: 'XXXX',
        encrypt: true
    }
}

var connection = new Connection(config);

function isConnected(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            connection.on('connect', function (err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                resolve(true);
            }
        }
    );
    })
}

isConnected().then(function(){
    // // queryDatabase();
})
```

Comment: Not found any other good pattern then this. So considering this, thanks!

Comment: It goes in chaining, How can I remove chain ?

Comment: You will always have to chain promises or wrap them up in a callback if you want stuff to happen sequentially

Comment: You can try async await it makes the code more readable, but an async function would also return a promise